# Regular expression to locate one string appearing anywhere after another but before someting

Tags: regex, powershell, edi

I have an EDI file. This is the piece in question:

N1*ST*TEST
N3*ADDRESS
N4*CITY*ST*POSTAL
PER*EM*TEST@GMAIL.COM
N1*BY*TEST
N3*ADDRESS
N4*CITY*ST*POSTAL
PER*EM*TEST2@GMAIL.COM

I am using powershell

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Temp\*.edi' | Where-Object {(Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern 'PER\*EM\*\w+@\w+\.\w+' -List)}
```

I want to find the email address that appears after the N1*ST, but before the N1*BY. I have the expression that works for an email address but I am stuck on how to only get the one value. The real issue is sometimes the email is there and other times it is not. So I really do want to ignore that second email after the N1*BY.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `N1\*ST[\s\S]+?(\w+@\w+\.\w+)[\s\S]+?N1\*BY` would put it in capture group #1 for you https://regex101.com/r/lVcvWv/1

Comment: I'm not familiar with PoweShell but if it supports variable-width lookbehinds then the regex could be improved further

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?s)(?<=N1\*ST.*)PER\*EM\*\w+@\w+\.\w+(?=.*N1\*BY)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%28%3F%3C%3DN1%5C*ST.*%29PER%5C*EM%5C*%5Cw%2B%40%5Cw%2B%5C.%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3D.*N1%5C*BY%29&i=N1*ST*TEST%0D%0AN3*ADDRESS%0D%0AN4*CITY*ST*POSTAL%0D%0APER*EM*TEST%40GMAIL.COM%0D%0AN1*BY*TEST%0D%0AN3*ADDRESS%0D%0AN4*CITY*ST*POSTAL%0D%0APER*EM*TEST2%40GMAIL.COM).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL (`RegexOptions.Singleline` in .NET) regex inline modifier making `.` match newline chars, too
- `(?<=N1\*ST.*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediaely preceded with `N1*ST`
- `PER\*EM\*` -a `PER*EM*` string
- `\w+@\w+` - 1+ word chars, `@`, and 1+ word chars
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?=.*N1\*BY)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediaely followed with `N1*BY` literal string.

**NOTE**: You need to read in the file contents with `Get-Content $filepath -Raw` in order to find the proper match.

Something like

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Temp\*.edi' | % { Get-Content $_ -Raw | Select-String -Pattern '(?s)(?<=N1\*ST.*)PER\*EM\*\w+@\w+\.\w+(?=.*N1\*BY)' } | % { $_.Matches.value }
```